# Accessing matrix in Python by an array of indices

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I'm relatively new to Python and would appreciate your help!

Suppose I have two square matrices - one large `M` and one smaller `K` - and an integer array of indices `ind`, not necessarily sorted. The length of `ind` matches the dimensions of `K`. In Octave/MATLAB, I can easily do this:

```
M(ind, ind) = K
```

This will distribute all the components of K to those positions of M that correspond to indices `ind`. This is often used in Finite Element computations.

Is there a way to do the same thing just as elegantly in Python? You may assume my `M` and `K` are NumPy arrays that were constructed via the operations:

```
M = np.zeros((12, 12))
K = np.zeros((6, 6))
```

I did some work on these matrices and filled them with data. My `ind` array is a NumPy array as well.
However, when I do something like

```
M[ind, ind] = K
```

I get `shape mismatch` as an error. Plugging `ind.tolist()` instead of `ind` into `M` won't change anything.

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: In `numpy` `M[ind, ind]` accesses a 'diagonal', while in MATLAB it defines a block.  `M[ind[:,None],ind]` gets the block, broadcasting a column vector against a row (1d array).  In effect what's easy in MATLAB is a bit harder in `numpy`.  But the reverse is true; MATLAB requires an extra function to get the 'flat' indices for a diagonal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for this:

```
M[np.ix_(ind,ind)] = K
```

example:

```
M = np.zeros((12, 12))
K = np.ones((6, 6))
ind = np.arange(6)
```

output:

```
[[1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using numpy arrays, It can be donde directly using this syntax:

```py
import numpy as np

M = np.zeros((12, 12))
K = np.ones((6, 6))

M[:6, :6] = K
# This is equivalent to:
# M[0:6, 0:6] = K
```

M will then look like this:

```
array([[1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

Here you have more information about slice indexing in python

https://www.pythoncentral.io/how-to-slice-listsarrays-and-tuples-in-python/

Comment: Is there a way to plug a given index numpy array? 0:6 is not what I'm looking for.